# Connection failure with SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2014

I'm already using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 and now I want to  upgrade to SQL Server 2014. But there is an error

> This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported

But connect via coding I got the data but not viewing table data in Server Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access correctly the Server Explorer using a lower version SSMS on a newer version of SQL Server (if that is what you mean).